# error: static_assert failed due to requirement '!is_signed<int>::value' "" static_assert((!is_signed<_Tp>::value), "");

Tags: c++, clang

note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__gcd' requested here
while (__gcd(n, k) <= 1) n++;

The above line was displayed along with the error shown earlier, I know there are many other methods to calculate gcd but I am confused why it's not working for (__gcd() ).

I am using MacBook :  OS -> BgSur

```
                  Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
```

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int getSum(int n)
{
    int sum;
    for (sum = 0; n > 0; sum += n % 10, n /= 10)
        ;
    return sum;
}
int main() {
    int t, n;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        cin >> n;
        int k = getSum(n);
        while (__gcd(n, k) <= 1) n++;
        cout << n << endl;
    }
}
```

here, getSum(125) = 1+2+5 = 8

INPUT :

```
3
11
31
75
```

OUTPUT:

```
12
32
75
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
12
33
75
```

Comment: Please add your exact input and expected output to the question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66890502/edit) the question.

Comment: In addition, that's not the error message. It's a line that gives you more context about the error. When you edit your question, include the full output from the compiler.

Comment: @Sneftel these two were the only line displayed by compiler

Comment: @UnholySheep no it actually isn't

Comment: @Ted-Lyngmo done !

Comment: Ok, I added the word _expected_ to it to make it clear - and also filled in what output you are currently getting. I hope that's what you actually get too :-)

Comment: @Ted-Lyngmo i am actually getting no output, just error

Comment: Ok, my bad. I removed that part. Are you really expecting `33` btw? Shouldn't it be `32`?

Answer (score 1):

As static assert suggests, your __gcd() implementation requires unsigned types for arguments (i.e. algorithm operates on non-negative numbers only), so replacing `int` with `unsigned int` should help - or you could replace

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>  // never include this
#include <cmath>
```

with

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>  // std::gcd
```

and use the GCD function that is included in the standard library instead:

```
while (std::gcd(n, k) <= 1) n++;
```

Comment: thank you, it helped me but now in second test case i.e 31 i am recieving 32 but correct answer is 33

Comment: @trev if `33` is expected you have some bug in your algorithm or in the implementation of your algorithm. I'd be surprised if it was related to the GCD function as such.

Comment: If the input that we are providing is positive(unsigned) then why should we care about what the data type is ? please explain.

Comment: @Ted-Lyngmo "I'd be surprised if it was related to the GCD function as such" why?

Comment: Re: _data type_: Because the GCD function you called is an internal (`bits`) implementation that _requires_ unsigned types. That's what the `static_assert` asserts.  Why I would be surprised? Because the GCD function has never made an error that I've seen. On my platform, both the internal `__gcd` and the standard `std::gcd` give `32`.

Comment: @Ted-Lyngmo okay, thank you.

Comment: @Dmitry why should we never use bits/stdc++ library ?

Comment: [Why should I **not** `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)

Comment: @Ted-Lyngmo The above code is perfectly working in windows laptop, is there any problem with MacOS ?

Comment: @trev Did you read the link? The code is not portable. It may not even work if you try to compile it with a newer or older version of the same compiler because you are using an _internal_ header file. It does not need to provide a stable API. It's also not available on all platforms. As you also noticed. My version of that internal function did _not_ have the `static_assert` problem that yours had. Non-portable.

Comment: @Ted-Lyngmo If the input that we are providing is positive(unsigned) then why should we care about what the data type is ? please explain.

Comment: I think you need to read what I've already written. I've already answered that question above (see "Re: _data type_").